# How to make a persistent connection to a web url in php?

Tags: php, http, curl, persistent

I am trying to make a persistent connection to a weburl and read the response from the url every moment (Connection will not be disconnected).

Looking for something like this.

`connection = connect("http://www.ibm.com?id=test");
 while(connection has response){
     //do something with the response until the connection in forcefully closed
 }`

I had a look into [pecl_http](https://pecl.php.net/package/pecl_http) library. But this will not serve the purpose.
Can we use curl to make a persistent connection to a web url?

Or is it something which is not supported in php?

Comment: How about `fopen()`?

Comment: Will the remote server keep streaming an endless HTTP response body…? HTTP doesn't seem like the best protocol for this, rather a web socket would be for streaming data.

Comment: Persistent connection doesn't mean `"hey, something changed, here's the content"`. How well do you understand HTTP protocol?

Comment: @deceze The API has a web socket and it stream data using https protocol. How do I go about it then? Create a web socket in my php application and then connect to the url?

Comment: So you really want to create a *web socket* connection, yes?

Answer (score 0):

Look how http protocol works. It's not possible to have persistent connection and receive event when content is changed. You can use websockets or long-polling.
Check this library found on github
https://github.com/panique/php-long-polling

Comment: It's certainly *possible*, it's just a bad use of HTTP and not very typical…

Comment: what the f are you smoking? it's fully possible to keep pushing data to a single http connection indefinitely. it's not gonna be easy if you're pushing to a web browser tho, cus of the caching n stuff the web browser is doing.  but with something like curl, it's no problem.

Answer (score 0):

use the socket api.

```
$sock=socket_create(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,SOL_TCP);
socket_connect($sock,"www.ibm.com",80);
$data=implode("\r\n",array(
'GET /?id=test HTTP/1.0',
'Host: www.ibm.com',
'User-Agent: PHP/'.PHP_VERSION,
'Accept: */*'
))."\r\n\r\n";
socket_write($sock,$data);
while(false!==($read_last=socket_read($sock,1))){
   // do whatever
    echo $read_last;
}
var_dump("socket_read returned false, probably means the connection was closed.",
"socket_last_error: ",
socket_last_error($sock),
"socket_strerror: ",
socket_strerror(socket_last_error($sock))
);
socket_close($sock);
```